# search location like iCal add event location in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I want to implement same functionality like **iCalendar** > **add event**> **Location search** in my iOS app.I am using google place autocomplete api but it only returns 5 records at a time. Is there any other way to do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Paneri

Answer (score 0):

You can't get more than 5 results. Looking at Google's [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete)

> predictions contains an array of places, with information about the
>   place. See Place Autocomplete Results for information about these
>   results. The Google Places API Web Service returns up to 5 results.